# PHP: Split text string into substrings not longer than 40 symbols without word breaks (spaces or “_” between words)

Tags: php, regex, string

I supposed to generate a grid with file names. The grid column for a filename is 45 symbols width. The words in filenames can be separated by spaces (“ “) or underscores (“_”), or can be one long word.

For example:

> My first file with a lot of interesting content in it.docx `(58 symbols)`
>
> My_second_file is also with_a_lot_of_content_and_pictures.zip `(61 symbols)`
>
> My lovely short file.odt `(24 symbols)`
>
> SplitMeWhereverYouWantButDontSortMeOutHoweverYouCanNeverNever.pdf `(65 symbols)`

The desired result is:

```
|=========================================| 
| My fist file with a lot of interesting  |
| content in it.docx                      |
-------------------------------------------
| My_second_file is also with_a_lot_of_   |
| content_and_pictures.zip                |
-------------------------------------------
| My lovely short file.odt                |
-------------------------------------------
| SplitMeWhereverYouWantButDontSortMeOutH |
| oweverYouCanNeverNever.pdf              |
```

My first idea was to use `wordwrap ($fileName, 40)` but that only will work for the fist filename. And this will not add the needed formatting. So I only figures out what to do with files shorter 40 symbols by using str_pad.

So my draft code for now is:

```
$grid = “|”.str_repeat(“=“,40).”|\r\n”;
foreach($filenames as $filename) {
  $grid .= “|”.str_pad($filename, 40).”|\r\n”;
  $grid .= “|”.str_repeat(“-“,40).”|\r\n”;
}
```

I don’t know how to split the other longer files.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You mean the example of PHP code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, ok. Fixed

Comment: Well, this `_` is a bit confusing, you seem to want to remove whitespaces, but keep `_` at the end of the previous line. Try `preg_replace('~\s*([^\s_]{39}|.{1,39}(?![^\s_])_*)~s', "$1$2\n", $filename)`, see [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/HsJDu)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That seems to work great! Then I probably `explode` It by “\n” and will be able to add proper formatting (str_pad and “|”) to each line. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace('~\s*([^\s_]{39}|.{1,39}(?![^\s_])_*)~s', "$1\n", $filename)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/WvIu4) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/49hLIn/1)

**Pattern details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (to be stripped)
- `([^\s_]{39}|.{1,39}(?![^\s_])_*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^\s_]{39}`  - 39 chars other than whitespace and underscores
  - `|` - or
  - `.{1,39}` - any 1 to 39 chars as many as possible but
  - `(?![^\s_])` - not immediately followed with a char other than whitespace or `_`
  - `_*` - 0 or more underscores.

The `s` modifier allows `.` to match any char including line break chars.